# How to eliminate duplicate rows joining on tables across databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, outer-join

I have been working on this script for a while and have reached a dead end.  The script works but unfortunately produces duplicates.  My script joins two different tables across databases on a state_issue_teacher_id key and then produces the output.  I have checked both tables and the row counts are the same and the join should match records perfectly but evidently there is a problem with my key or the way I'm joining to the table and my output is coming back partially incorrect.  I've also tried concatenating attributes to make a unique key and join the tables but still producing incorrect results.

Here is my script:

```
SELECT     
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.year_time)) AS 'year_time' ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.state_issue_teacher_id)) AS state_issue_teacher_id ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.district_code)) AS district_code ,
       rt.district_name ,
       rt.school_name ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.assignment_code)) AS assignment_code ,
       rt.assignment_desc ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.position_code)) AS position_code ,
       rt.position_desc ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.last_name)) AS last_name ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.first_name)) AS first_name ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.total_salary)) AS total_salary ,
       rt.assign_fte ,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(rt.school_code)) AS school_code ,
       rt.fte

    FROM    staging.dbo.rt AS rt

    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT   LTRIM(RTRIM(dti.year)) AS year ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(dt.teacher_id)) AS teacher_id ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(db.district_code)) AS district_code ,
                    db.district_name ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(dt.last_name)) AS last_name ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(dt.first_name)) AS first_name ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(da.assignment_code)) AS assignment_code ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(dp.position_code)) AS position_code ,
                    dre.race_ethnicity_code ,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(db.school_code,10,4))) AS school_code ,
                    da.assignment_desc ,
                    dp.position_desc ,
                    fs.total_fte

           FROM     mart.dbo.fact_s AS fs
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_building
                    AS db ON fs.building_key = db.building_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_teacher
                    AS dt ON fs.teacher_key = dt.teacher_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_assignment
                    AS da ON fs.assignment_key = da.assignment_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_race_ethnicity
                    AS dre ON dt.race_ethnicity_key = dre.race_ethnicity_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_gender
                    AS dg ON dt.gender_key = dg.gender_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_time
                    AS dti ON fs.time_key = dti.time_key
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.dbo.fact_s.dbo.dim_position
                    AS dp ON fs.position_key = dp.position_key
           WHERE    dti.year = '2012'



         ) raw ON    rt.state_issue_teacher_id = raw.teacher_id                 
                        AND rt.year_time = raw.year 
                        AND rt.last_name = raw.last_name 
                        AND rt.first_name = raw.first_name 
                        AND rt.district_code = raw.district_code
                        AND rt.position_code = raw.position_code
                        AND rt.school_code = RAW.school_code
                        AND rt.assignment_code = raw.assignment_code



    WHERE   rt.year_time = '2012'



    ORDER BY rt.last_name, rt.first_name
```

The output that I'm getting is:
[image]

The fte for the combined teachers assignments should add up to 1.  But teachers that have the same assignment_code/desc with multiple partial assignments are producing duplicates. Example: Jane Doe appears 4 times with a total fte of 2.0 instead of 2 times with the correct total of 1.0.  The output should read as follows.
[image]

Comment: So you don't want something like

SELECT "all columns of interest" FROM staging.dbo.rt AS rt, mart.dbo.fact_s AS fs WHERE rt.state_issue_teacher_id = fs.teacher_id AND rt.year_time = fs.year AND rt.year_time = '2012';

Comment: What are the primary keys on both tables?  (The same row count does not guarantee that the resulting join also has the same number of rows.)

Comment: The Pk is the state_issue_teacher_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be getting the duplicates for part-time teachers that have multiple assignments, with all the descriptions of the assignment being the same.  This is quite clear from the first four rows of your actual output versus the first two of the desired output.

I wonder why you would have those duplicates to begin with.  However, they are in the fact table so there must be something important (I suppose two part-time guidance counselors are funded rather than one full-time one).  Does the fact table really have exact duplicate records in this case?  If not, the fields that are not duplicated may suggest an additional join key that will fix the problem.

You need to get rid of the Cartesian product produced by this join condition:  `rt.assignment_code = raw.assignment_code`.

Apart from finding a better join key, I can think of two ways to fix this.  The first would be to create a really unique id for the positions.  Perhaps in your data structure you know of one.  Or, you could use `row_number()` to add a sequence number for people who have multiple positions.

The other way would be to eliminate the duplicates on one side or the other.  For instance, you might aggregate `rt` to eliminate such duplicates.

Comment: Gordon these duplicates do not exist in the fact or staging tables with both mart and fact having the correct results having multiple assignments.  And there is not a better unique join key in either table.  This is part of an overall data validation process and I'm trying to avoid manipulating the original source file.  I tried concatenating several attributes together for an additional join key but did receive the same duplication errors.

Comment: @Tone . . . I observe that you are getting a Cartesian product when the assignment descriptions are the same, but not when they are different.  The easiest explanation is that these rows are duplicated on both sides, joined by the assignment code, and there is something else left out: Either an explicit key or an implicit one (possibly because the database was designed without considering one person having multiple identical assignments).